# Architectural blockchain adoption possibilities

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain

I am working on a new shipments management project which will need the blockchain technology to certify the app-generated documents.

I have no prior experience in blockchain and after a deep browsing session I have gathered these possibilities to integrate blockchain in the project:

1. Join a private/consortia blockchain with the installation of a related node in an on-prem/cloud server
2. Deploy a private/consortia blockchain using Hyperledger frameworks/tools on on-prem/cloud servers
3. Deploy a public blockchain using Ethereum frameworks/tools on on-prem/cloud servers (Not sure if applicable since I am working on a enterprise project)
4. Create a blockchain solution via BaaS providers as Azure, AWS, Alibaba,...

Questions:

1. Are the above possibilities correct?
2. If not, what solutions should I leverage?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your requirements, and can't be answered simply. To help guide your thinking, I'd suggest:

#### 1) Is a blockchain really needed?

You have said you are new to this space, so perhaps review your requirement against the charts here:
https://medium.com/@sbmeunier/when-do-you-need-blockchain-decision-models-a5c40e7c9ba1

#### 2) Public or Consortium

Should you be considering a public or consortium blockchain? Note that "public" here means to use an existing public chain (eg Ethereum Mainnet), not to deploy a new chain publicly. There are some good arguments for using public chains from EY https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAmNjJRtLGo but again this depends on your requirements.

#### 3) Tech

Then think about what tech to use. If you've chosen public chain, then there is no infrastructure to setup, you just use mainnet. If you've chosen consortium, then there is some tech listed here: https://ethereum.org/enterprise/#why-enterprise-ethereum. Once you've chosen the tech you can think about on-prem, cloud, BaaS and so on.

To be honest blockchain tech is a huge space, even if we just restrict ourselves to Ethereum. If you are completely new you may want to take some external consultancy to guide you.

Comment: Many thanks! I really appreciate your suggestions.